# How to send a message with discord oAuth API

Tags: go, discord

I have a go api, and we are trying to send a message on a channel thanks to oAuth2.
So far, we retrieved the token and we can display some user information (email, username etc...)

we are trying to retrieve some message, but we have an "unauthorized" error.
I read some documentation about permissions, i think i have to do somethings with header, but i'm totally new to golang.

can you help me? :)

this is the code :

```
func HelloDiscord(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

conf := &oauth2.Config{
    RedirectURL: "http://localhost:8080/auth/discord",
    ClientID: "clientid",
    ClientSecret: "clientsecret",
    Scopes: []string{discord.ScopeIdentify},
    Endpoint: discord.Endpoint,
}


token, _ := conf.Exchange(context.Background(), r.FormValue("code"))
fmt.Println(token)

message, err := conf.Client(context.Background(), token).Get("https://discord.com/api/channels/1021410887191507004/messages")


fmt.Println("message;")
fmt.Println(message)
if err != nil || message.StatusCode != 200 {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    if err != nil {
        w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
    } else {
        w.Write([]byte(message.Status))
    }
    return
}

defer message.Body.Close()

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(message.Body)

if err != nil {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
    return
}

w.Write(body)
```

}

thanks a lot